Is there a way to use SVG <animateMotion> to make a customized polygon to follow a specific path moving?
Updated: solved.
I noticed that the circle can follow the path smoothly, but the triangle behaves differently compared to the circle. Is there a way to make the triangle move along the path smoothly as well?
Here's my pen:SVG Animation


<svg viewBox="0 0 200 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid blue">
    <path
  id="motionPath"
  fill="none"
  stroke="gray"
  stroke-width=2
  d="M20,50 L40,20 80,90 110,50" />

  <circle r="5" fill="red">
    <animateMotion
    dur="8s"
    repeatCount="indefinite">
    <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"/>
    </animateMotion>
  </circle>
    
    <polygon points="20,10 10,20 30,20" fill="red" transform="translate(-20, -16.67)">
  <animateMotion
  dur="8s"
  repeatCount="indefinite">
  <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath"/>
  </animateMotion>
  </polygon>
</svg>




You need to align the triangle around the x/y origin. Each elements' drawing x/y coordinates are interpreted as offsets when moving them along a motion path. In other words: motion paths won't auto-align/center elements

@herrstrietzel Thx. I calculated the centroid of the triangle, and added the transform="translate(-20, -16.67)" to it. Then it works.
